# Failed to look up JNDI DataSource In Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, spring-boot, jndi

I have done the bellow mentioned configuration for JNDI DataSource connection for Spring Boot Application that uses an external tomcat.

Tomcat's server.xml configuration like

```
         <GlobalNamingResources>
            <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
                 UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
            -->

            <Resource name="jdbc/MyPostgresDB" 
              global="jdbc/MyPostgresDB" 
              auth="Container" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" 
              username="postgres" 
              password="postgres" 

              maxActive="100" 
              maxIdle="20" 
              minIdle="5" 
              maxWait="10000"/>
```

Context.xml like

```
        <Context>

            <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
            <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

            <ResourceLink name="jdbc/MyPostgresDB"
                        global="jdbc/MyPostgresDB”
                        auth="Container"
                        type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Defined the application.properties for spring boot in right way like

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/MyPostgres
```

Updated the web.xml like

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <resource-ref>
        <description>JNDI LookUp</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyPostgresDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <!-- <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope> -->
    </resource-ref>

    </web-app>
```

Still getting the exception like

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
>   Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
>   'java:comp/env/jdbc/MyPostgres'

(Full Stacktrace not given as every where it is given)

So what is the solution or why I am getting this exception.

Don't come with the idea of embedded tomcat server for spring boot.
Please help me.

Comment: Defined the application.properties for spring boot in right way like spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/MyPostgresDB Still getting the exception(In the original post it was typo mistake sorry for that)

Answer (score -1):

Should be

> spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/MyPostgres**DB**

from what you wrote above in your definitions.

Comment: Sorry it is exactly same what you told I have posted it wrong, but still getting the error

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Answer (score -1):

we should add factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" in Resource tag of server.xml and make sure to set JndiDatasource in the class where you extends SpringBootServletInitializer class

For elaborate answer please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558980/run-spring-boot-in-eclipse-with-tomcat-for-externalising-datasource/43593642#43593642)

Comment: The link does not exists